# Form Fields generated based on variable types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project utilizing ASP.NET MVC and Razor page layouts. The page in question will be a survey whose questions, datatypes, and answers have been configured by an admin user and retrieved from a database. For example:

```
public class ExampleViewModel 
{
    //the user define dquestion
    public string Question1Text { get; set; }

    //this is an enum with "Text","YesNo","DropDown"
    public AnswerType Question1Type { get; set; } 

    //this would hold options for the drop down list
    public string Question1Options { get; set; }

    //the user input answer
    public string Question1Answer { get; set; }
}
```

What I am not sure is how to structure the Razor view to create the appropriate type of form input field depending on the AnswerType. I seem to recall something about creating templates for the various DataType() annotations but I am not sure where to start looking at that and if that applies in this case?

Comment: If its OK to group each type in the view, then using a view model with 3 collection properties for each question type would be easiest. Note also you will need additional properties - a `bool` for the 'Yes/No` answer and a `SelectList` for the multiple choice options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Templated Helpers - Here is a good walkthrough - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

In the helper itself you can do stuff like:

```
@if (model.AnswerType is xxx)
{
     <button> xxx </button> - or your html
}
```

etc